# Displaying attribute from a csv file in Python when it contains 1 or 2 other named attributes

Tags: python, opencsv, read.csv

I'm new to python and would really appreciate some help please.  I've created a file of car attributes in Excel and saved it as a csv file, called cars.csv like this:

```
Car make, colour, price, number of seats, automatic, petrol
Ford, black, 40000,5,yes,no
Tesla, white, 90000,4,yes,no
```

After the headings, I have 20 lines with different cars and their attributes.

Could someone help me with the python code which returns all the makes of cars which have say 4 seats, or say cost 40000, or say both these attributes?  Thankyou.

Comment: Can you install external libraries?

Comment: Yes, I've already done import csv and filename = cars.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('cars.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
print(df)

# Output
  Car make colour  price  number of seats automatic petrol
0     Ford  black  40000                5       yes     no
1    Tesla  white  90000                4       yes     no
```

Filter your dataframe

```
out = df[(df['number of seats'] == 4) | (df['price'] == 40000)]
print(out)

# Output
  Car make colour  price  number of seats automatic petrol
0     Ford  black  40000                5       yes     no
1    Tesla  white  90000                4       yes     no
```

You can also read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: Thankyou.  That helps somewhat.  Is there a way to bring back just a list of car makes which cost 40000, and nothing else (there are 10 car makes in my table which cost 40000.  I don't want any other attributes brought back, just the car makes (which cost 40000. Thankyou Corralien.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pandas.loc[] function here. If you load the csv with pandas, you can use the loc function to select only the rows that match your conditions.

```
import pandas as pd

# if index was dropped when saving the csv
car_atts = pd.read_csv('path to file as string')

# if index was not dropped
car_atts = pd.read_csv('path to file as string', index_col=0)

4_seater_cars = car_atts.loc[car_atts['number of seats'] == 4]

# if col name is type string
fourty_k_cars = car_atts.loc[car_atts['40000'] == True]

# if col name is type int
fourty_k_cars = car_atts.loc[car_atts[40000] == True]

# you can use the & (AND) to find rows that match both conditions
4_seater_fourty_k_cars = car_atts.loc[
    (car_atts['number of seats'] == 4) &
    (car_atts['40000'] == True)
]

# you can use the | (OR) to find rows that match either condition
4_seater_fourty_k_cars = car_atts.loc[
    (car_atts['number of seats'] == 4) |
    (car_atts['40000'] == True)
]
```

Hope this answers your question.

Happy coding!!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but getting the following  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: @Stormy1 propably you have to install pandas with pip installer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-python-pandas-on-windows-and-linux/

Comment: @Stormy1, that is correct. You need to install pandas in your environment. Simply open a terminal and type `pip install pandas` from within your working environment. Then you can restart your kernel and the import should work. If you are using vscode, you can do it directly from the embedded terminal, or if working in a jupyter notebook in vscode, you can type `!pip install pandas` into any code cell and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use any library you can use this approach

```
# The return value of this method can be handled like a list, but its called a generator object
# This method loads all cars from the csv file and yield this data
def load_cars():
    with open('Cars.csv', 'r') as f:
        for counter, line in enumerate(f):
            if counter > 0:# I skipped the header row
                line_content = line.split(", ")
                producer, colour, price, number_of_seats, automatic, petrol = line_content
                yield producer, colour, price, number_of_seats, automatic, petrol # This is like one item in the list

# The statement below is called a list comprehension
# the load_cars method returns the list like object and it iterates over each object, which is put in car
# The car is put in the list if the condition after the if keyword is true
# Each car which fulfills the condition is in the new created list
filtered_cars = [car_data for car_data in load_cars() if car_data[3] == "4" and car_data[2]=="40000"]
filtered_car_names = [car_data[0] for car_data in filtered_cars]
```